# Форма и api [ASP.NET MVC]

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Есть проект который выводит погоду из api на страницу веб-браузера. Сейчас погода выводится только по одному городу:

```
string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Kharkiv&APPID=" + key + "&units=imperial";
```

Нужно сделать чтоб пользователь запрашивал любой город, для этого сделал форму

```
<form action="Index" method="post">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:18px">Enter city:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="city" />
                <input type="submit" id="search" value="Search"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
</form>
```

**Как эту форму привязать к api запросу в asp.net?**
Model:

```
  public class Weather
{
    public Object getWeather()
    { 

        string key = "03e45b7211028e0119ce0b1b3fa9fa90";
        string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Kharkiv&APPID=" + key + "&units=imperial";

        var client = new WebClient();
        var content = client.DownloadString(url);

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<Object>(content);

        return jsonContent;
    }
}
```

Views:

```
...<script>
var weather = Object();
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.get("@Url.Action("GetWeather", "Home")", function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            weather = ko.mapping.fromJS(response);
            ko.applyBindings(weather);
        });
});
```

Comment: Что конкрето вам не понятно то? Если не понятно ничего, то вам надо пройти курс или книжку по ASP.NET MVC почитать.

Comment: Начните с того, чтобы в контроллере getWheather добавить входной параметр - string city, которую подставлять вместо q=Kharkiv. А для этого стоит подумать, вы хотите post параметр или get параметр (пока вижу склонность к get судя по js)

Comment: @tym32167 конкретно: как передать текст из input в url вместо q=Kharkiv

Comment: @AK string city {get; set;}? хочу get

Comment: нет, нужно public `Object getWeather(string city)`

Comment: @AK ага, к существующей модели добавить параметр сity, и потом присвоить его url q={city}?

Comment: не знаю, что вы называете "существующей моделью" (привели её код в вопросе? похоже, что нет), но насчёт присвоить - да, верно, я уже писал об этом выше.

Comment: @AK я про класс Weather (который есть выше)

Comment: Нда, я понял почему его не нашёл: потому что я думал, что это контроллер. Он содержит логику того ЧТО НУЖНО ДЕЛАТЬ. А модель [данных] - это ДАННЫЕ, а не ПРОЦЕСС. Так что вы просто в модель, где должны быть поля/свойства/данные зачем-то воткнули логику, которая не должна в этом классе находится. Так что это уже не модель, это уже вермишелькод.

Comment: @AK Ага, разобрался, спасибо за помощь!